# Differences between functions and objects, and how it affects performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Could anyone shred some light on why there seems to be such a great difference in memory footprint between the two examples shown below? I'm using node.js as environment.

They both produce the same result and mapping

```
var util = require('util');

var startMem = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;

/*
var test = function() {

    var testvar = function() {
        this.innerTest1 = function() {
            this.someVal1 = "this is a test";
            this.someFunc1 = function() {
                return "this is another test";
            }
        }
        this.innerTest2 = function() {
            this.someVal2 = "this is a third test";
            this.someFunc2 = function() {
                return "this is a forth test";
            }
        }
    }
}
*/
//out:
//mem: 448088


var test = function() {
    var testvar = {
        innerTest1 : {
            someVal1 : "this is a test",
            someFunc1 : function() {
                return "this is another test"
            }
        },
        innerTest2 : {
            someVal2 : "this is a third test",
            someFunc2 : function() {
                return "this is a forth test"
            }
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var testobj = new test();
}

//out:
//mem: 1060040


console.log("mem: " + (process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - startMem));
```

Comment: Is the loop also part of the first example?

Comment: These are not doing the same thing at all

Comment: if you did not call innerTest1 and innerTest2 in your first test case, then comparison is not fair: someVal1/someFunc1 and someVal2/someFunc2 won't get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two snippets of code have entirely different behavior.

In the first example, the properties/functions are *not set or created* until the containing functions are invoked. However, the containing functions are *never* invoked.

For instance, given:

```
   this.innerTest1 = function() {
        // the property is NOT SET until this function is run
        this.someVal1 = "this is a test";
        // this function is NOT CREATED until this function is run
        this.someFunc1 = function() {
            return "this is another test";
        }
    }
```

Likewise, the same applies for assigning to `innerTest1`. Thus, the first example code is equivalent the following which is not very useful.

```
var testvar = function() {}
```

(The parsing can be considered a one-time cost.)

In the later example, *every* property is assigned and *every* function is created as part of the object literal evaluation.

Comment: Ahh ok, makes sense. So it would be the same memory footprint if every function and property were called in the loop, in the first example?

Comment: @Rasive I'm not going to say "the same", but it will be much closer - or at least wildly different from the previous numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example functions are getting created lazily only when their *parent* function is called, but in the second example all members are initialized as part of the object literal.

**If you are trying to reduce your memory footprint**, you should make use of the prototype chain which will allow you to share functions between multiple instances.

Basically, rather than doing:

```
function test() {
    var testvar = {
        someFn: function () {}
    };
}
```

You can do:

```
var base = {
    someFn: function () {}
};

function test() {
    var testvar = Object.create(base);
}
```